# Sort IEnumerable object by property name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ienumerable

Please refer below code

```
public class NNAEmployeeDetails
    {
        public string DealerCode { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<NNAEmployeeDetails> empList =GetList();
```

i am trying the sort the above ienumerable by Employeename by below code

```
empList.OrderBy(s=>s.EmployeeName)
```

but OrderBy itself not showing in empList. Please refer below image

[image]

why the OrderBy is not coming in empList ? is  any namespace problem ? what is the exact behavior ? how to sort ienumerable by EmployeeName ?

Comment: It's a namespace problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a `using` for `System.Linq` to access the LINQ extension methods.

Also note that `OrderBy` doesn't mutate the sequence, it *creates a new sequence* that is ordered.